# Finite index of a subgroup of an infinite group

Tags: group-theory

It's mentioned in herstein that there can be infinite groups whose subgroups have finite index.
I cannot think of any examples.
Some examples would be useful

Comment: A related interesting phenomenon is that infinite groups can have subgroups of finite order. The group of non-zero real numbers under multiplication incorporates the subgroup $\{-1, 1\}$ which I thought was quite amazing.

Comment: I am surprised that you cannot think of any examples, since the infinite cyclic group, which must be just aboout the best known infinite group, is an example.

Comment: Yes. I was making a foolish mistake

Comment: The trivial subgroup has infinite index in any infinite group...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The even integers in the integers. Any nontrivial subgroup of the integers.

Comment: How is it finite?

Comment: It has finite index, which is what  you asked about.

Comment: Formally the index of a subgroup is equal to the number of cosets. $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}$ will have two cosets, namely: $0+\mathbb{2Z}$ and $1+\mathbb{2Z}$, therefore the index is 2.

Comment: Oh yess! I was confusing it with infinite order of each coset. A very foolish mistake.